# PreparedStatement "is null" in Where clause without if conditional (dynamic query) or gibberish values

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Suppose I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?
```

With PreparedStatement, I can bind the variable:

```
pstmt.setString(1, custID);
```

However, I cannot obtain the correct results with the following binding:

```
pstmt.setString(1, null);
```

As this results in:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = NULL
```

which does not give any result. The correct query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL
```

The usual solutions are:

### Solution 1

Dynamically generate query:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID "
                + (custID==null ? "IS NULL" : "= ?");
if (custID!=null)
    pstmt.setString(1, custID);
```

### Solution 2

Use `NVL` to convert null value to a gibberish value:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE NVL(CUSTOMER_ID, 'GIBBERISH') = NVL(?, 'GIBBERISH');
```

But you need to be 100% sure that the value 'GIBBERISH' will never be stored.

### Question

Is there a way to use a static query **and** avoid depending on gibberish value conversions? I am looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE /** IF ? IS NULL THEN CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL ELSE CUSTOMER_ID = ? **/
```

I think I may have a working solution:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE ((? IS NULL AND CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL) OR CUSTOMER_ID = ?)

pstmt.setString(1, custID);
pstmt.setString(2, custID);
```

**Will the above work reliably?** Is there a better way (possibly one that requires setting the parameter only once)? Or is there no way to do this reliably at all?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN(?)` comes to mind. Not sure.

Comment: @JoopEggen It doesn't work. Same results as `=` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working solution is fine (and similar to what [I've used before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811331/266304)). If you only want to bind once you can use a CTE or inline view to provide the value to the real query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ? AS REAL_VALUE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT C.*   -- but not * really, list all the columns
FROM CTE
JOIN CUSTOMERS C
ON (CTE.REAL_VALUE IS NULL AND C.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL)
    OR C.CUSTOMER_ID = CTE.REAL_VALUE
```

So there is only one placeholder to bind.

I don't really see a problem with a branch on the Java side though, unless your actual query is much more complicated and would lead to significant duplication.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about CTEs as well but hoping for something simpler. Yes, the actual query is much more complicated and would lead to significant duplication. The problem with asking questions here with simple examples here is that many automatically assume that our actual situations are also equally simple. PS: *"but not * really, list all the columns"* I know `:)` it's just an example here.

Comment: @ADTC - I guessed it might be, and the `*` thing is sort of outside the scope anyway - hence just a code-comment nudge in case *8-)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 
  DECODE(CUSTOMER_ID, NULL, 'NULL', CUSTOMER_ID || 'NOT NULL') =
  DECODE(?, NULL, 'NULL', CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID || 'NOT NULL')
```

This works, I believe

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5c518/4)

Note that in order to test it on sqlfiddle I have had to replace the parameter with a value for each case [NULL, 'NULL', 'SMITH']

Comment: Interesting, but convoluted. You're stretching "Solution 2" but can you prove that your version will not have the problem with it? Also, how would the performance be?

Comment: Can I prove it will not have which problem with it?  Performance will depend on your setup.  I don't think my answer is quite ready - give me a minute.

Comment: Ah, the problem of failing when the substitution values are actually stored in the column (in your case, the magic values 'NOT NULL' and 'NULL'). I also think your query is not matching a specific non-null value.

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle example, if someone happens to be called 'NULL' it correctly identifies him - also NULL and 'SMITH' ...

Comment: @adtc - it is convoluted because it is a tricky little piece of logic.  Let me know how the test goes on SqlFiddle, please

Comment: This would prevent an index on `customer_id` (if there is one, which seems plausible) being used to find not-null values.

Comment: That is correct, as does the `NVL()` approach in your question, but it does solve the issue of the rogue value being a potential real value.  You could squeeze a little bit of extra performance by replacing `'NULL'` & `'NOT NULL'` with `'X'` & `'Y'`

Comment: @HughJones Tried as per [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66e0e/6). It's working very nicely without errors, but I think it will have performance issues with large value sets as it uses `DECODE` and concatenation (`||`). Anyway nice effort!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically creating the query works on all JDBCs, so you are not bound to platform-specific SQL.
It wouldn't be that hard to read to create an `if`-branch, would it?

```
PreparedStatement pst = null; // Avoid initialisation warnings
if (custID == null)
    pst = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL");
else {
    pst = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?");
    pst.setString(1, custID);
}
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: This is no different from Solution 1 that I already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ADTC Not much, but to me this is more readable. Also it only null-checks once (Your code checks twice).

Comment: Refactoring my simple example to be "more readable" or "more efficient" does not make the basic premise different. It's still the same logic. I'm not looking for this.

Comment: @ADTC Okay, I would sure like to know why you want that then?

Comment: What I want: Already mentioned in question (under *Question* section). *"why you want that"* I don't understand. I am not looking for Solutions 1 or 2, refactored or otherwise.

Comment: @ADTC well, I am looking for a reasoning behind _not_ using one of your already found solutions.

Comment: (1) query becomes dynamic unnecessarily, or (2) reliance on magic values (a dirty method)

Comment: I don't consider (2) acceptable either, but the query in (1) is dynamic while the alternative "outsources" the dynamics to the DB only somewhat hiding it in code. But okay I think I understand what you mean.